# Is there a way to use pandas with a blob link?

Tags: python, pandas, blob

I'm trying to read this file with pandas, perferrably without downloading it:

blob:https://worldpopulationreview.com/26dd60b4-4e76-4c4a-8762-bc639acc2790

However, when I try to use

```
pd.read_csv('blob:https://worldpopulationreview.com/26dd60b4-4e76-4c4a-8762-bc639acc2790')
```

I get

```
ValueError: Protocol not known: blob:https
```

Without the blob part, I get a 404 error. The link is from here:

https://worldpopulationreview.com/state-rankings/electoral-votes-by-state

Comment: something is wrong with your URL.  Try to open it in my browser and I get 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative approach, `read_html()`

```
pd.read_html("https://worldpopulationreview.com/state-rankings/electoral-votes-by-state")[0]
```